# Bootstrap datetimepicker month/year selection ignores sidebyside=false

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have this datetimepicker configured as:

    `$(".dateTimePickerElement").datetimepicker({
       toolbarPlacement: "top",
       showTodayButton: true,
       sideBySide: false,
       showClear: true,
       showClose: true,
       useCurrent: true,
       keepOpen: true,
       locale: "en",
       format: "YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A",
       debug: true
   });`

When the year month is clicked to make a selection of months or years, it ignores sideBySide: false and shows up wide on the screen on other elements.
[image]
Did not find a solution anywhere.
Thanks for help

Comment: By default it's on false so I think you can remove it. Can you provide a simple fiddle maybe ?

Comment: Sorry could not make time for the fiddle during work hours.

Comment: @EkjonS did you end up solving the problem please. I need a solution to the same exact problem.